# Full Text search result sort order

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on fulltext search to display result based on searching by name and definition.
The problem is the results are generated in random order.

```sql
SELECT people_id,
       people_name,
       people_definition,
       created_at,
       status.status_name AS status
FROM   people
JOIN   status
ON     people.status_id = status.status_id
WHERE  Match(people_name, people_definition) against ('"group"' IN boolean mode)
```

All the column values are in random order. So any idea why it generates this kind of result, what's the logic behind it?

Answer (score 1):

Relational database tables have no record order and when you query them records could be returned in any order. If you want the records listed in a specific order then you need to include an ORDER BY clause in your SQL